# Need help with my Apex & VF

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm struggling to understand why my code isn't working as expected. I'm not an expert, still in the learning phase.

I have a VF page [image]

I'm trying to do a total of the values entered in each column and display at the bottom. Code below,

```
public class BPSection {

private Id Brokerid;

public PageReference edit() {
    return null;
}

public BPSection(Apexpages.StandardController stdcontroller){
    BrokerId = [SELECT Broker__c FROM BD_Profile__c WHERE Id  = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id') LIMIT 1].Broker__c;
    BPSection();
}

public List<BD_Profile__c> InsList{set;get;}
public List<BD_Profile__c> InsListtoShow{set;get;}
public boolean showInputTable{set;get;}
public boolean showOutputTable{set;get;}
public void BPSection(){

    showInputTable = true;
    showOutputTable = false;
    InsList = new List<BD_Profile__c>();


    BD_Profile__c b1 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b1.Insurer__c = 'ACE/Chubb';
    BD_Profile__c b2 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b2.Insurer__c = 'AIG';
    BD_Profile__c b3 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b3.Insurer__c = 'Allianz';
    BD_Profile__c b4 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b4.Insurer__c = 'Aspen';
    BD_Profile__c b5 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b5.Insurer__c = 'AVIVA';
    BD_Profile__c b6 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b6.Insurer__c = 'AXA';
    BD_Profile__c b7 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b7.Insurer__c = 'Beazley';
    BD_Profile__c b8 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b8.Insurer__c = 'C N A';
    BD_Profile__c b9 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b9.Insurer__c = 'Covea';
    BD_Profile__c b10 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b10.Insurer__c = 'Ecclesiastical';
    BD_Profile__c b11 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b11.Insurer__c = 'HCC';
    BD_Profile__c b12 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b12.Insurer__c = 'Hiscox';
    BD_Profile__c b13 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b13.Insurer__c = 'HSB';
    BD_Profile__c b14 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b14.Insurer__c = 'Liberty Mutual';
    BD_Profile__c b15 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b15.Insurer__c = 'LV=';
    BD_Profile__c b16 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b16.Insurer__c = 'Market Corp';
    BD_Profile__c b17 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b17.Insurer__c = 'NFU Mutual';
    BD_Profile__c b18 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b18.Insurer__c = 'NIG';
    BD_Profile__c b19 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b19.Insurer__c = 'NMU';
    BD_Profile__c b20 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b20.Insurer__c = 'QBE';
    BD_Profile__c b21 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b21.Insurer__c = 'RSA';
    BD_Profile__c b22 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b22.Insurer__c = 'Tokio Marine';
    BD_Profile__c b23 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b23.Insurer__c = 'Travelers';
    BD_Profile__c b24 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b24.Insurer__c = 'XL Catlin';
    BD_Profile__c b25 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b25.Insurer__c = 'Zurich';
    BD_Profile__c b26 = new BD_Profile__c();
    b26.Insurer__c = 'Other Insurers';

    InsList.add(b1);
    InsList.add(b2);
    InsList.add(b3);
    InsList.add(b4);
    InsList.add(b5);
    InsList.add(b6);
    InsList.add(b7);
    InsList.add(b8);
    InsList.add(b9);
    InsList.add(b10);
    InsList.add(b11);
    InsList.add(b12);
    InsList.add(b13);
    InsList.add(b14);
    InsList.add(b15);
    InsList.add(b16);
    InsList.add(b17);
    InsList.add(b18);
    InsList.add(b19);
    InsList.add(b20);
    InsList.add(b21);
    InsList.add(b22);
    InsList.add(b23);
    InsList.add(b24);
    InsList.add(b25);
    InsList.add(b26);



}
public void Save(){
     Decimal PackagesTotal = 0;
     Decimal FleetTotal = 0;
     Decimal MotorTradeTotal = 0;
     Decimal PCCombinedTotal = 0;
     Decimal ConstructionTotal = 0;
     Decimal PropertyOwnerTotal = 0;
     Decimal PITotal = 0;
     Decimal DOTotal = 0;
     Decimal MarineTotal = 0;
     Decimal EngineeringInsTotal = 0;
     Decimal EngineeringInspTotal = 0;
     Decimal OtherCommLinesTotal = 0;
     Decimal PersMotorTotal = 0;
     Decimal HouseholdTotal = 0;
     Decimal OtherPersLinesTotal = 0;

    InsListtoShow = new List<BD_Profile__c>();

    For(BD_Profile__c p:InsList){
        if(PackagesTotal != null){
            if(p.Packages__c != null){
                PackagesTotal+=p.Packages__c;
                System.Debug('>>>>>>> the value of p is' +p);
            }
        }
        if(FleetTotal != null){
            if(p.Fleet__c != null){
                FleetTotal+=p.Fleet__c;
            }
        }
        if(MotorTradeTotal != null){
            if(p.Motor_Trade__c != null){
                MotorTradeTotal+=p.Motor_Trade__c;
            }
        }
        if( PCCombinedTotal != null){
            if(p.P_C_Combined__c != null){
                PCCombinedTotal+=p.P_C_Combined__c;
            }
        }
        if( ConstructionTotal != null){
            if(p.Construction__c != null){
                ConstructionTotal+=p.Construction__c;
            }
        }    
        if( PropertyOwnerTotal != null){
            if(p.Property_Owner__c != null){
                PropertyOwnerTotal+=p.Property_Owner__c;
            }
        }        
        if( PITotal != null){
            if(p.PI__c != null){
                PITotal+=p.PI__c;
            }
        }            
        if( DOTotal != null){
            if(p.D_O__c != null){
                DOTotal+=p.D_O__c;
            }
        }                
        if( PITotal != null){
            if(p.PI__c != null){
                PITotal+=p.PI__c;
            }
        }            
        if( MarineTotal != null){
            if(p.Marine__c != null){
                MarineTotal+=p.Marine__c;
            }
        }            
        if( EngineeringInsTotal != null){
            if(p.Engineering_Insurance__c != null){
                EngineeringInsTotal+=p.Engineering_Insurance__c;
            }
        }            
        if( EngineeringInspTotal != null){
            if(p.Engineering_Inspection__c != null){
                EngineeringInspTotal+=p.Engineering_Inspection__c;
            }
        }            
        if( OtherCommLinesTotal != null){
            if(p.Other_Comm_Lines__c != null){
                OtherCommLinesTotal+=p.Other_Comm_Lines__c;
            }
        }            
        if( PersMotorTotal != null){
            if(p.Pers_Motor__c != null){
                PersMotorTotal+=p.Pers_Motor__c;
            }
        }            
        if( HouseholdTotal != null){
            if(p.Household__c != null){
                HouseholdTotal+=p.Household__c;
            }
        }         
        if( OtherPersLinesTotal != null){
            if(p.Other_Pers_Lines__c != null){
                OtherPersLinesTotal+=p.Other_Pers_Lines__c;
            }
        }         


                            p.Broker__c = BrokerId;
            InsListtoShow.add(p);
            }


         insert InsListtoShow;
         BD_Profile__c p = New BD_Profile__c();   
         p.Insurer__c = 'Total Broker Account';
         p.Packages__c = Packagestotal;
         p.Fleet__c = FleetTotal;
         p.Motor_Trade__c = MotorTradeTotal;
         p.P_C_Combined__c = PCCombinedTotal;
         p.Construction__c = ConstructionTotal;
         p.Property_Owner__c = PropertyOwnerTotal;
         p.PI__c = PITotal;
         p.D_O__c = DOTotal;
         p.Marine__c = MarineTotal;
         p.Engineering_Insurance__c = EngineeringInsTotal;
         p.Engineering_Inspection__c = EngineeringInspTotal;
         p.Other_Comm_Lines__c = OtherCommLinesTotal;
         p.Pers_Motor__c = PersMotorTotal;
         p.Household__c = HouseholdTotal;
         p.Other_Pers_Lines__c = OtherPersLinesTotal;

         InsListtoShow.add(p);
         ShowInputTable = false;
         ShowOutputTable = true;

 }                            

}
```

The totalling seems to work okay for the first time on a column and when I enter a value in another column for summation it seems to go back to the Inputpage for some reason. 
VF below,

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="BD_Profile__c" extensions="BPSection">   
<apex:form >
  <apex:pageblock rendered="{!showInputTable}">
      <center><apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/></center>
          <apex:pageblockTable value="{!InsList}" var="p" align="center">
              <apex:column headerValue="Insurer"><b><apex:OutputField value="{!p.Insurer__c}"/></b></apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Packages"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Packages__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px;"/> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Fleet"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Fleet__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px"/> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Motor Trade"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Motor_Trade__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px" /> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="P&C Comb"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.P_C_Combined__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px" /> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Construction"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Construction__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px" /> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Prop Owner"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Property_Owner__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px" /> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="PI"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.PI__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px" /> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="D&O"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.D_O__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px" /> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Marine"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Marine__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px" /> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Eng Ins"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Engineering_Insurance__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px" /> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Eng Insp"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Engineering_Inspection__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px" /> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Other CL"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Other_Comm_Lines__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px" /> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Pers Motor"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Pers_Motor__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px" /> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Household"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Household__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px" /> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Other PL"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Other_Pers_Lines__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px" /> </apex:column>
          </apex:pageblockTable> 
      <center><apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/></center>
  </apex:pageBlock>   

  <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!showOutputTable}"> 
      <center><apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/><apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!edit}"/></center>

          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!InsListtoShow}" var="p" align="center">
              <apex:column headerValue="Insurer"><b><apex:OutputField value="{!p.Insurer__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px"/></b></apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Packages"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Packages__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px"/> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Fleet"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Fleet__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px"/> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Motor Trade"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Motor_Trade__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px"/> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="P&C Comb"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.P_C_Combined__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px"/> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Construction"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Construction__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px"/> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Prop Owner"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Property_Owner__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px"/> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="PI"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.PI__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px"/> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="D&O"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.D_O__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px"/> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Marine"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Marine__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px"/> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Eng Ins"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Engineering_Insurance__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px"/> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Eng Insp"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Engineering_Inspection__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px"/> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Other CL"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Other_Comm_Lines__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px"/> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Pers Motor"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Pers_Motor__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px"/> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Household"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Household__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px"/> </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Other Pers Lines"> <apex:inputField value="{!p.Other_Pers_Lines__c}" style="width: 3.66vw;height: 12px"/> </apex:column>

           </apex:pageBlockTable>
       <center><apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/></center>       

  </apex:pageBlock>  
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Can someone take a look and let me know how to make this work please? Any help will be greatly appreciated, Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that when you do a save, you only want it to rerender the 2nd pageBlock where you have `!showOutputTable`. You need to put an `Id` on that pageblock and add that to both of your commandButtons to tell the visualforce to only reRender that portion of the page.

**Edit**

Part of your issue is that you're not actually doing a "Save" in your method. Save means something very specific to VisualForce when you use it in a CommandButton with a StandardController. It thinks that you're writing data to the database and thus need to reset the page afterward or redirect to a detail page. I recommend you rename your method (and perhaps the button too) to something like show or display records. See the [VisualForce Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_std_actions.htm) for more on this topic (couldn't find the exact reference I was looking for, but this one gives you the idea). Once you do that and add the appropriate rerender tag, I suspect that should solve your issue.

Comment: Many thanks! I tried added the following, <apex:pageBlock id="outputtable" rendered="{!showOutputTable}"> <center><apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}" reRender="outputtable"/> still doesn't work. thoughts?

Comment: See my edited answer. I think the issue is related to association with Save Action.